# Play Framework as reverse proxy with ScalaWS

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket

I am trying to document a server and replicate its setup done by another person. Server is running Play Framework which also acts as a reverse proxy to MediaWiki running on Apache on the same server on a port that is not open externally on the server.

The Play Framework routes requests to the Media Wiki Server using [ScalaWS](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS). When I check the request it creates a request by using the server domain with the Apache port and the media wiki file.

In the real server it is working fine but in the test deployment it fails to reach mediawiki. It works if in the test deployment I open the Apache port externally.

So Somehow the request to the local server running internally on the machine needs to be accessed without routing the request externally. How can this be done? If anyone can give some quick tips or things I can check or even explain how this may be working, that would really help save me some time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the test environment? Also, the sbt tool is very flexible and sometimes some customizations may be present. You got to be aware of the details of the workflow, that is, what plugins are run and the configs. Without these details, most efforts would be blindly guessing, I think.

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/hosts file had the wrong domain defined. Fixing that fixed the problem.